Equivalent Connector for Create Block Blob in Azure Standard Logic App

I know We have to use In-App Connectors/Triggers in the Azure Standard Logic App. if they are not available, then we use have to use the shared connectors.
Here I have used all type of connections like Managed Identities, Entra Id Integrated, etc but no luck.
If I use "Upload blob to storage container" connector, then it is able to upload the file to the blob container but when I download it but If I download the file, it is showing the file is corrupted.

Can any of the experts help me here.

What do you want to do? Create a block blob in Storage account right? Can you give your input that needs to be sent to storage account? –
RithwikBojja

Sure, I want to upload the excel file/any type file came as attachment in the mail to the blob container and when I download that file from the container, it should come as-it-is without any errors. As I'm using Standard Logic App, I tried with in-app connector 1st - uploading successfully but when I download the file gets corrupted. So I tried to used the create block blob connect but I cannot able to connect to storage account.

What do you want to do? Create a block blob in Storage account right? Can you give your input that needs to be sent to storage account?

I replied in the question(modified) as it some big info.


As I'm using Standard Logic App, I tried with in-app connector 1st - uploading successfully but when I download the file gets corrupted. So I tried to used the create block blob connect but I cannot able to connect to storage account.

You can use below design to get desired results:

You have to given path as :
/containername/foldername/etc

Connecting to Blob Storage :
Give the name and primary/secondary access key for connecting it:

Output:

Then in Storage Account, the blob is created:


If you are using Managed identity Connection:

You should give name and container name as below:
So just give name as it is because it is using managed identity you have to give like below:

In Storage account give the role :
Storage Blob Data Owner

Output:


